# How to get a menubar for latest version of libre office

Tags: libreoffice

I am trying to simply insert an image in to my document, but there is no insert menu.
There is no lo-menubar in the Ubuntu software center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hovering your mouse on the bar along the very top of your screen. The File, Insert, and other menus should appear there. At least, that was where they appeared by default for me on Ubuntu 14.04.

I personally prefer that the menus appear on the title bar of the window I'm working in, so I changed the setting as follows:

System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior -> Show the menus for a window -> In the window's title bar